# VSCode-like integrated terminal functionality in nvim? (eg: open files mentioned in terminal output in a buffer)

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim

I'm coming from VSCode to Neovim, and for the most part I've been able to accommodate/replicate the workflows and functionality I've gotten used to in VSCode in Vim. Right now, I'm stuck on replicating the [Link functionality of the VSCode integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_links).

This lets you mouse over text like `main.py` or `server.go:50` and ctrl-click to jump to that file or line location in your editor panes. This really helpful for jumping to the locations of compilation errors or test failures from their associated terminal output.

I've searched for existing plugins/solutions for this but haven't found any. Are there any that I've missed? Otherwise, what might be a good approach to scripting this myself?

I'm new to vimscripting, but I'd assume you could do some regex and with knowledge of the current working directory, you could infer the correct filepath to open.

Answer (score 0):

Replicating one editor's workflow in another is not exactly a good idea as the two editors have—supposedly, if not why switch in the first place?—different feature sets or even paradigms. For instance, staying in insert mode all the time in Vim because that's what you are used to would make no sense because Vim derives most of its value from its modality… and you would probably also find examples in the other direction.

Case in point, compiling and jumping to errors in Vim typically doesn't involve the built-in `:terminal` *at all*. You are supposed to use the `:help quickfix` feature, which exists for that very purpose.

See `:help 30.1` for a gentle introduction from the user manual.

Comment: Point taken on workflows and I certainly have a ways to go with learning the 'Vim' ways to do things. However, I found exactly what I was looking for as a native Vim command: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor.

Comment: @gonfy; i read that article too. did you manage to jump to the file to the exact line number using `wincmd f` ?